# Can you use if/else statements to style divs in erb?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Sorry if this is terribly asked; this is my first post on here. I am using erb for ruby on rails and I want to know if I can make a background-color of a div differ based on user selection. I looked online and couldn't find an answer. I am new and am still trying to learn how to search.

```
            <div class="row">
    <% @stores.each do |store| %>
        <div class="col s12 m6">

        <% if store.color = 'red' %>
            <% profile_color = 'red' %>
        <% elsif store.color = 'blue' %>
            <% profile_color = 'blue' %>
        <% elsif store.color = 'green' %>
            <% profile_color = 'green' %>
        <% elsif store.color = 'orange' %>
            <% profile_color = 'orange' %>
        <% end %>


            <div class="card <%= profile_color %> center">
                <div class="card-content white-text">
                    <span class="card-title"> <%= store.name %> </span>
                    <h6>Owner: <%= store.owner %> </h6>
                    <h6>Location: <%= store.location %> </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action" >
                    <%= link_to 'Visit Store', store_departments_path(store) %>
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_store_path(store) %>
                    <%= link_to 'Delete', store_path(store), method: :delete,
                         data: {confirm: 'Really Delete?'} %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I use a form that asks the user for a color and they pic from a drop down that is the type string. I have checked and @store.color is storing the color and everything.

Comment: You're confusing comparison `==` with assignment `=` which means this code does not do what you want it to. A safer alternative is using `case` which breaks out conditions, or in this case since you're just testing vs. a white-list, `list.include?(store.color)` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `profile_color` is defined in the scope of each `if` so when you reach the class attribute is nil, as I see the if's aren't doing anything more than assign the same value, you can change:

```
<div class="card <%= profile_color %> center">
```

To use the `store.color` like:

```
<div class="card <%= store.color %> center">
```

And remove all the if's

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to set the `profile_color` variable using `if`/`else` statements and then output it in the `class` attribute as you have.

The problem with this particular code is that

```
if store.color = 'red'
```

doesn't check whether `store.color` equals `'red'`, it *assigns* the value `'red'` to `store.color` and then checks whether the value `'red'` is truthy. It is truthy (anything other than `false` or `nil`), so `profile_color` should get set to `'red'` no matter what the original value of `store.color` was.

You want to use

```
if store.color == 'red'
```

instead. Though as has been pointed out in other answers, if `profile_color` is always going to be the same as `store.color`, you could just use `store.color` in the `class` attribute and skip `profile_color`. If you want to make sure that only certain values can be put in `class`, then you could probably check whether `['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange'].include?(store.color)` and not add anything to `class` if it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, why don't you just do something like this

```
<% @stores.each do |store| %>
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <div class="card <%= store.color %> center">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <span class="card-title"> <%= store.name %> </span>
                <h6>Owner: <%= store.owner %> </h6>
                <h6>Location: <%= store.location %> </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action" >
                <%= link_to 'Visit Store', store_departments_path(store) %>
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_store_path(store) %>
                <%= link_to 'Delete', store_path(store), method: :delete,
                     data: {confirm: 'Really Delete?'} %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No that is exactly what I needed. The simplest thing ever. I overthink everything so thanks